# Getting rid of commit after completing Pull Request in GitHub repository

Tags: github, git-commit

I'm trying to create a Pull Request in GitHub repository from one branch to another branch. On completing the Pull Request, I see 2 commits being added:

[image]

Is there a way to get rid of the commit "Merge pull request from ..." via settings?

In ADO repository, there is an option to "Rebase and fast-forward" to get rid of that commit. Is there something similar in GitHub?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When merging a pull request on GitHub, you have **3 options** when you click on the *drop down button* beside the button to merge the PR:

- **Create a merge commit**
- **Squash and merge**
- **Rebase and merge**

[image]

While the first one is selected by default, you can choose the 2nd or 3rd option in case you want to avoid the merge commit as mentioned in your question.

All the 3 options are also explained in detail in this GitHub [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/merging-a-pull-request#merging-a-pull-request-on-github).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to make sure that the commit number won't change after PR completion? On using Rebase and merge option, I see commit number in master branch is different from the source branch after PR completion.

Comment: @user989988 The commit hash would always change when merging the PR with the 2nd and 3rd options, it would only remain the same if you're using the "Create a merge commit" option, but it would create the extra merge commit that you saw earlier.